# Version upgrade error 2.3.5p2 to 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Run: `composer update`

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1**

```
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.0 requires pelago/emogrifier ^3.1.0 -> satisfiable by pelago/emogrifier[3.1.x-dev, v3.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.0 requires pelago/emogrifier ^3.1.0 -> satisfiable by pelago/emogrifier[3.1.x-dev, v3.1.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
- Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.0].
```

Help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your server requirements using these commands below.

```
curl -O https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:check
```

If everything is good to go, you can run these commands to remove the cache and run the composer update again.

```
composer clearcache
rm composer.lock
composer update -vvv
```

If it doesn't work I recommend checking your composer.json comparing [to the original one from Magento 2.4](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.json).